how to configure to display of indic fonts

file contents contain text in indic language
filename contain indic language text
text is displayed as garbage in both files and filename
how to find languages supported by android os using emacs and how to configure emacs?


Instead of trying to edit my answer, edit your question to include the additional information.

Emacs already supports all languages and all scripts. It might help to show us a screenshot of the “garbage” that you see, and what you expected to see.
Also, if you can run describe-language-environment (bound to C-h L by default) and tell us at least the first few lines of what it says that might help too. It will prompt you for the name of a language environment; just press enter to use the current one, which is the one we care about. It should look something like this:
UTF-8 language environment

This language environment is a generic one for the Unicode character set
encoded in UTF-8.

Input methods (default rfc1345)
  rfc1345 ("m" in mode line)
  korean-hangul3 ("한390" in mode line)
  korean-hangul390 ("한390" in mode line)
  korean-hangul3f ("한3f" in mode line)
  korean-hangul ("한2" in mode line)
  ucs ("U+" in mode line)
  sgml ("&" in mode line)
  TeX ("\" in mode line)
  emoji ("" in mode line)
  iso-transl ("X8" in mode line)
  compose ("+" in mode line)

Character sets:
  unicode-bmp: Unicode Basic Multilingual Plane (U+0000..U+FFFF)
  unicode: Unicode (ISO10646)

Coding systems:
  utf-8 (‘U’ in mode line):
    UTF-8 (no signature (BOM))
    (alias: utf-8 mule-utf-8 cp65001)

[back]

Edit:
Since your default language environment is English you should set it to UTF-8, or to a language environment customized to the language you prefer. You can run M-x set-language-environment to do that. You can make it permanent by adding (set-language-environment "UTF-8") to your init file. There are several language environments for Indian languages such as Devanagari, Gujarati, Gurmukhi, Sinhala, etc. These all use UTF-8 as their coding system, but they pick a different default input method that you might prefer.
Of course there is also the possibility that the files you want to edit are not actually in the UTF-8 encoding. This is exceedingly unlikely, but you might need to change additional settings to accommodate these files.

output of  describe-language-environment: ```English language environment
Nothing special is needed to handle English.
Sample text:
Hello!, Hi!, How are you?
Input methods:
programmer-dvorak ("DVP@" in mode line)
english-dvorak ("DV@" in mode line)
Character sets:
ascii: ASCII (ISO646 IRV)
Coding systems:
nothing specific to English``` default:english
